# Adding text to a MS Word table in vb.net too slow

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, automation

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928826/vb-net-adding-tables-to-word-document) and many other examples on the internet one can figure out how to automate the text addition to a MS Word table:

```
ProductTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "whatever text here"
```

But the problem is that the process is so slow that you can even see the lines being added one by one.

This is not a problem for a small application, but in my case I need to add about 6000 rows of text.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try, whether it is faster, if you first add the complete table content in CSV manner and then convert it to table with Range.ConvertToTable method.

E.g. in Word VBA:

```
With ActiveDocument
 Set myRange = .Paragraphs(.Paragraphs.Count).Range
 myRange.Text = _
 "data11,data12,data13" & vbCrLf & _
 "data21,data22,data23" & vbCrLf & _
 "data31,data32,data33" & vbCrLf
 myRange.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdSeparateByCommas 'not necessarily commas, depends on the Locale properties
End With
```

Greetimgs

Axel